# ZF2: how do I get ServiceManager instance from inside the custom class

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get ServiceManager instance from inside the custom class.

Inside the controller it's easy:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('My\CustomLogger')->log(5, 'my message');
```

Now, I created a few independent classes and I need to retrieve `Zend\Log` instance inside that class. 
In zend framework v.1 I did it through static call:

```
Zend_Registry::get('myCustomLogger');
```

How can I retrieve the `My\CustomLogger` in ZF2?

Comment: In addition to Jerry's answer I would advice you to just inject the dependency you need in the custom class. So if you only need the logger object in your custom class then make the factory of your custom class inject the logger instance when creating a new instance of your custom class.

Comment: As Sam and Ruben pointed out, it would be better to NOT have your class depend on the ServiceManager. Instead, it would be better to inject the logger into the class directly. You could do this either through an Initializer that looks for a "custom" LoggerAwareInterface OR make a factory class for your custom class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make your custom class implement the `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`.

When you instantiate it with the ServiceManager, it will see the interface being implemented and inject itself into the class.

Your class will now have the service manager to work with during its operations.

```
<?php
namespace My;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

class MyClass implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface{
    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;


    public function doSomething(){
        $sl = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $logger = $sl->get( 'My\CusomLogger')
    }
}

// later somewhere else
$mine = $serviceManager->get( 'My\MyClass' );

//$mine now has the serviceManager with in.
```

Why should this work?

This works only in the context of the Zend\Mvc, which I assume you're using because you mentioned a controller.

It works because the `Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig` adds an initializer to the ServiceManager.

```
$serviceManager->addInitializer(function ($instance) use ($serviceManager) {
    if ($instance instanceof ServiceLocatorAwareInterface) {
        $instance->setServiceLocator($serviceManager);
    }
});
```

Give it a try and let me know what happens.

Comment: The general approach is correct, however i want to hint that you should ideally not have the ServiceLocator as a dependency, but only the stuff that you need FROM the serviceManager (i.e. the logging class or the db adapter or whatnot)