# php: Confused about the way the "use" keyword is used in this code snippet

Tags: php, oop, interface

I [found a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888728/zf2-how-do-i-get-servicemanager-instance-from-inside-the-custom-class) that made use of the php "use" keyword in a way I did not understand. Here is the code snippet:

```
<?php
namespace My;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

class MyClass implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface{
    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;


    public function doSomething(){
        $sl = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $logger = $sl->get( 'My\CusomLogger')
    }
}

// later somewhere else
$mine = $serviceManager->get( 'My\MyClass' );

//$mine now has the serviceManager with in.
```

Now I tried this code without the `use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;` line and it doesn't work. Why would you have to do `use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;` when you already have `use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;` at the top of the page. Is that like a special way to initialize a method required by the interface with default values or something?

Comment: One is a namespace. One includes a trait.

Comment: Wow, didn't even know what "traits" were. I have some reading to do thanks.

Comment: Here you go then: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php (traits are PHP 5.4+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'use' outside of the class declaration is importing other namespaces - classes/interfaces.

The one inside the Class declaration is importing a Trait into the Class, so the class can have access to trait's behaviour.

namespaces - http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php
traits - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php